# create firebase database rule on key name

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need help on creating a firebase database rule. The use case is like this: the user (gamer) have 3 treasure boxes which can hold any treasure. User can purchase extra treasure box. So the tree structure in firebase database I came up is:

```
user
  |- settings
       |- max-t-box : 3
  |- boxes
       |- 1 : {} // a complicated data for the treasure or null
       |- 2 : {} // a complicated data for the treasure or null
       |- 3 : {} // a complicated data for the treasure or null
```

The rule on 'user/settings/max-t-box' is trivial: user read only and not allowed to write (it can only be modified by server side admin).

The rule under 'user/boxes' is supposed to be: the key of new data should be a number and it's value should be > 0 and <= 'user/setting/max-t-box' value.

According to firebase document, I can use $variable to capture path segment, however it does not provide enough api for me to check the path node name value.

So far the solution I come up is to write rules for path 'user/boxes/1', 'user/boxes/2' and 'user/boxes/3'. However this really looks stupid after user buys many boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to run into a *lot* of issues using sequential numbers as keys. They are (can be) treated like an array and in Firebase [Arrays Are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) and should generally be avoided.

Arrays cannot be modified, searched and if you want to modify them, they have to be totally re-written.

Structuring your data using push() or childByAuto() to create your keys is the way to go:

```
root
     settings
       max-t-box 3

    boxes
       -yuy8jj09j9090f
         box_num: 1
         box_name: "Big box"
         box_location: "Sewer"
       -y8jokokoais9g
         box_num: 2
         box_name: "Small box"
         box_location: "Tower"
```

and then the rules are a snap

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "boxes": {
      "$box_num": {
        ".validate": "newData.child('box_num').val() > 0 && 
                      newData.child('box_num').val() <= 
                                        root.child('settings').child('max-t-box').val()" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I did this directly within the root node but you can substitute the root.child('users') for your firebase structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the post and answer! I think we need to bend our mind a little bit to think in Firebase way.