# Deleting an Item in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following data in Firebase:

[Before Deletion (Link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1cYz.png)

In the "-Kabn1954" branch, I want to delete the item "apple". Using Swift, I delete an item at a specific index, in a particular branch, using this:

```
self.ref.child("-Kabn1954").child("foods").child("1").removeValue()
```

However, after I do this, the Firebase data looks like this:

[After Deletion (Link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6AEP.png)

As you can see, the data in this branch now goes directly from index 0 to index 2. For this reason, I get an error. How can I make it such that when the item at index 1 is deleted, the two remaining items have an index of 0 followed by an index of 1?

Comment: [Such cases are the reason that usage of objects are preferred over arrays](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html). I dont have any idea whether it's (objects) applicable in swift or not, but you can check this resource for [Synchronized Arrays](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/05/handling-synchronized-arrays-with-real.html).

Comment: Please avoid using arrays in NoSQL databases. [Arrays are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) and check out answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179477/firebase-changing-layout-of-child-data-information-in-android/43191862#43191862) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45785134/create-firebase-database-rule-on-key-name/45804389#45804389). In general, create keys with childByAutoId and store key:value pairs within those parent nodes. It makes it editable, queryable and much easier to support.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase doesn't [actually store the data as an array](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html), instead it stores it as an object keyed by the index as you're observing. The guide suggests that you should try to restructure your data so that the array-like behavior is not used.

If that is not possible or really not preferable, I don't know about how the Swift API works, however in both the python and JavaScript libraries, if you observe on the parent `foods` element, you'll get an array object which you can splice and push an update. I'm guessing this is also true in Swift, as the [API indicates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#value) that an `NSArray` can be returned too.

As the blog post mentions, you'll need to update the entire array when you want to reindex, as Firebase will not do it for you. `setValue()` [accepts an](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseReference(im)setValue:) `NSArray` which can be called on the `foods` reference. Be careful about race conditions here, you'll want to encapsulate the read and write into a single transaction to avoid losing your update.