# How to retrieve data in firebase database in ios app? My JSON data looks like this and I want to get each value associated with questiontext, A...E

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nsdictionary

JSON data are following:

```
{
    "Questions": {
        "1": {
            "questiontext": "Which choice best describes what happens in the\npassage?",
            "A": "One character argues with another character who intrudes on her home.",
            "B": "One character receives a surprising request from\nanother character",
            "C": "One character reminisces about choices she has\nmade over the years.",
            "D": "One character criticizes another character for\npursuing an unexpected course of action.",
            "E": "null"
        },
        "2": {
            "questiontext": "Which choice best describes the developmental pattern of the passage?",
            "A": "A careful analysis of a traditional practice",
            "B": "A detailed depiction of a meaningful encounter",
            "C": "A definitive response to a series of questions",
            "D": "A cheerful recounting of an ammusing anecdote",
            "E": "null"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find there are some challenges with your structure so that will probably need to be changed in the future.

Since your question is very specific about the included structure, here's how to access the value of Question 1, Answer A (or B, C, D etc)

```
let q1Ref = self.ref.child("Questions").child("1")
let q1Ref_a_ref = q1Ref.child("A")
q1Ref_a_ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let answer = snapshot.value as! String
    print(answer)
})
```

The output is

```
One character argues with another character who intrudes on her home.
```

Now, if you want to get all the child nodes A-E, then here's the code

```
let q1Ref = self.ref.child("Questions").child("1")
q1Ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let key = snap.key
        let value = snap.value as! String
        print("Answer \(key) is \(value)")
    }
})
```

and the output will is

```
Answer A is One character argues with another character who intrudes on her home.
Answer B is One character receives a surprising request from\nanother character
Answer C is One character reminisces about choices she has\nmade over the years.
Answer D is One character criticizes another character for\npursuing an unexpected course of action.
Answer E is null
```

To address a comment; this assumes your Firebase root ref is defined thusly:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.ref = Database.database().reference()
```

and your firebase structure keys are 1, 2, 3 (as in an array*) and not "1", "2", "3"

You can tell the difference by looking at your Firebase console and seeing if the keys are surrounded by quotes;  1 is different than "1"

It would be a good idea to use .childByAutoId to create parent node keys instead of numerics (array)

*Arrays should be avoided in Firebase. See [Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45785134/create-firebase-database-rule-on-key-name/45804389#45804389)

Comment: I tried the above code and it didnot work. I tried debugging by adding a print lines in the middle. It seems like it works until the q1Ref (since i could print the https of the firebase with the q1Ref) and then it fails to enter the code from here:- q1Ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

Comment: @AppManiac The above code does work as it was copied and pasted directly from a working project. The output included in my answer is the actual copy and paste from the XCode console. One difference would be if your Firebase structure is slightly different than what was included in your question. The other issue is how your Firebase ref is defined. I have it defined as a class var of 'ref' so then I can use self.ref to access my Firebase root reference.

Answer (score -1):

```
    if let question = jsonData["Questions"] as? [String: Any] {

    //Question 1
    if let questionOne = question["1"] as? [String: Any] {
        for (key, value) in questionOne {
            print("\(key):\(value)")
        }
    }

    //Question 2
    if let questionTwo = question["2"] as? [String: Any]{
        for (key, value) in questionTwo {
            print("\(key):\(value)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but i need to access it directly from firebase

Comment: What does this answer do? i.e. how would it load the specified nodes from firebase and enable the OP to access the discreet answers associated with the A, B, C etc nodes?