# Sending data to Firebase as an array is giving me bugs

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As of now, my data base is structured like this - which works for me. But here is the mishap i am having - These two nodes separated by auto ID's are actually the same post.

If you see the previous was my DB was structured (using an array), you will see that each post could have multiple images, dates and plans. which worked well, but gave me nightmares when trying to access indices and such. So i switched to this more advisable way. But now i am having issues grouping the posts together. For instance, these two below should be apart of the exact same post.

**How would i be able to assure that when i read data from my DB - i group each auto ID node together with their appropriate posts?** ie: These two nodes are actually the same post - as you can tell by them each having the same title.

```
   Planit
     -LETR-XJvQsZCOpG-T1N
        Uid: "ZjtJdkjzuxc0mZn4u9TfWsXa9jh2"
        date: "Jun 9, 2018 at 10:00 AM"
        image: "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.c..
        plan: "Bike Rodeo, Safety Presentation and Riding Tour o"
        title: "This weekend Plans?"

     -LETR-XKqXf7NY1gh6Jm
        Uid: "ZjtJdkjzuxc0mZn4u9TfWsXa9jh2"
        date: "Jun 11, 2018 at 10:00 AM"
        image: "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.c..
        plan: "Fun night out at the Parlor"
        title: "This Weekend Plans?""
```

**My DB was previously structured in this way**- which worked perfect on a functional level, but was wrong by Firebase programmatic principals. and i am only putting this in so you can tell the structure that i actually need, these posts need to be grouped in someway so that when i read the from FB and load them into a table view, the appropriate data is stored together - *For example - 1 post can have 2 images, 2 plans, and 2 dates, but only 1 TITLE (of post).*

```
Plant: 
 -LETYTJh1WEHGgGcVCEp
    dates
       0: " "
       1: " "
    images
       0: " "
       1: " "
    plans
       0: " "
       1: " "
    senderId
       0: " "
    title: close
```

Below is the function i use to push the data to Firebase - i looped through an array so that each iteration would push the images, dates, plans, title as one "bunch".

```
    for planits in chosenPlanArray {
        DataService.instance.uploadPlanitData(withTitleOfPlan: [planits.nameOfEvent!], 
           withDate: [planits.eventStartsAt!], 
           withImage: [planits.imageForPlan!], 
           withTitle: nameOfPlanit.text!, 
           forUID: (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!, 
           sendComplete: { (isGood) in

            if isGood {

            }
        })
    }
```

And here is my actual implementation in the Data Service Class

```
func uploadPlanitData(withTitleOfPlan plan: [String], withDate: [String], withImage: [String], withTitle: String, forUID uid: String, sendComplete: @escaping (_ status: Bool) -> ()) {


    _REF_PLANITS.childByAutoId().updateChildValues(["plan" : plan, "date" : withDate, "image": withImage, "title": withTitle, "Uid": uid])
    sendComplete(true)
}
```

Comment: Glad you are changing direction as Array's are not well suited for NoSQL databases. Here's a few links to some questions and answers here on SO that may give you some direction. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179477/firebase-changing-layout-of-child-data-information-in-android/43191862#43191862) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45785134/create-firebase-database-rule-on-key-name/45804389#45804389) and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166876/how-do-i-design-a-simple-firebase-database-that-stores-arrays/42170435#42170435)

Comment: It's going to be hard to directly answer the question as to *what is the best alternative to uploading arrays*. For me, early on, I realized that Firebase (JSON) is really just a big Dictionary. *Everything* is a key: value pair. While keys are single elements, values can be strings, numbers, and most interestingly, another dictionary of a key:value pair. So, 2 things; 1) update your question with information as to *what you want to get out of Firebase* e.g. what kind of queries will you need? 2) Please don't include screen shots in your questions; include code and structures as text snippets.

Comment: @Jay sorry, i was at work - just got off. But thank you for your suggestions, after reading your response, you gave me a lot of insight and clarity on the topic. So, is it possible for me to store an array as a :value pair? & sorry i thought the screenshots would be give more clarity but i guess not. Understood.

Comment: In general don't use arrays. Their use is very situational and there are (usually) much better options to store data. Read through the links I included in my prior comment. Again - the mechanics of pushing data in a specific format is dictated by what you want to get out of firebase. i.e. I want to query for posts from yesterday. Or, I want to I want to show the top 5 liked posts. etc. Define that, update your question and then a proper structure can be crafted - the code to make that happen will then fall into place.

Comment: @Jay Hey, so i literally just seen your response about updating the question to get a proper structure, can you please take a look at this question. Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50750787/need-to-figure-alternative-to-saving-array-in-firebase

Comment: Looks like it was deleted. Perhaps you can update this question with a bit more information like your requirements and/or what isn't working.

Comment: Hey thanks for response @Jay .. I will update the question within the next 30 minutes on my work break. Thanks again

Comment: @Jay edited - looking forward to any suggestions. Please take your time and thank you for the consideration

Comment: @Jay i hope the question is clear and understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the question and there are a few ways to go about it.

**1) Group within the post**

```
PlanIt
 plans
  -LETR-XJvQsZCOpG-T1N
    Uid: "ZjtJdkjzuxc0mZn4u9TfWsXa9jh2"
    date: "20180609"
    images:
       image_0: "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.c.."
       image_1: "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.c.."
    plans
       plan_0: "Bike Rodeo, Safety Presentation and Riding Tour o"
       plan_1: "Bike Rodeo, Safety Presentation and Riding Tour o"
    title: "This weekend Plans?"
  -Yjijiioimoifijjiuee
    Uid: "asdaasdas"
    etc
```

The keys of image_0, image_0, plan_0, plan_1 etc would be created with childByAutoId.

With this, you can load a post once and you get all of the needed child data with it.

Note that while this structure appears 'deep' which is usually discouraged in Firebase NoSQL, you won't be performing any queries on the deep data and that data is specific to the post so it's fine in this case.

**2) Denormalize/Flatten the structure**

```
PlanIt
 plans
  -LETR-XJvQsZCOpG-T1N
    Uid: "ZjtJdkjzuxc0mZn4u9TfWsXa9jh2"
    date: "20180609"
    title: "This weekend Plans?"
  -UYijs09as9jiosdijfi
    Uid: "some uid"
    date: "20180609"
    title: "some title"

 all_images:
    -LETR-XJvQsZCOpG-T1N
       image_0: "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.c.."
       image_1: "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.c.."

 all_plan_details
    -LETR-XJvQsZCOpG-T1N
       detail_0: "Bike Rodeo, Safety Presentation and Riding Tour o"
       detail_1: "Bike Rodeo, Safety Presentation and Riding Tour o"
```

the second option would require an initial loading of the post node to obtain it's key and then one call to the all_images node to load the images and a call to all_plans to get it's plans. Note that I am using the posts key to reference  the all_images and all_plans child node.

The idea here is that we use the key of the PlanIt child as a reference to that node within the all_images and all_plans node. image_0, image_1, plan_0, plan_1 are keys generated with .childByAutoId

The second option is kind cool because for example, say you have a tableview with a list of just titles and dates and then when the user taps it, you can load images or plans into another view... This option would be loading far less data at a time which makes it a bit more manageable memory wise.

**EDIT**

To clarify the process, here's the code to read in the plan, images and plan details and print them to the console based on the structure above.

```
let mainRef = self.ref.child("PlanIt")
let plansRef = mainRef.child("plans")
let allImagesRef = mainRef.child("all_images")
let allPlanDetailsRef = mainRef.child("all_plan_details")

plansRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

 for child in snapshot.children {
     let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
     let dict = childSnap.value as! [String: Any]
     let planKey = childSnap.key
     let title = dict["title"] as! String

     let thisPlansImagesRef = allImagesRef.child(planKey)
     let thisPlansDetailsRef = allPlanDetailsRef.child(planKey)
     thisPlansImagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { imageSnapshot in

         thisPlansDetailsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { planDetailSnapshot in
             //printing is done here because firebase is asynchronous and all data 
             //  will be valid for each node ONLY at this point
             print("plan: \(planKey)  \(title)")
             for imageChild in imageSnapshot.children {
                 let imageChildSnap = imageChild as! DataSnapshot
                 let image = imageChildSnap.value as! String
                 print("  image: \(image)")
             }

             for planDetailChild in planDetailSnapshot.children {
                 let planDetailChildSnap = planDetailChild as! DataSnapshot
                 let planDetail = planDetailChildSnap.value as! String
                 print("  planDetail: \(planDetail)")
             }
         })
     })
  }
})
```

and the output will be:

```
plan: plan_0  This weekend plans
  image: some image for plan_0
  image: another_image for plan_0
  planDetail: some plan detail for plan_0
  planDetail: another plan detail for plan_0
plan: plan_1  Next weekend plans
```

I added some text values within my Firebase so it would be more clear what's going on in the output.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes you understood the question exactly! One question though- wouldn’t I eventually run into the same “array” issues though by implementing solution 1 or 2? It seems like they are both still being stored as an array aren’t they?

Comment: @CodingwhileLoading No an array in the the Firebase sense is an ordered array of integers, 1,2,3,4 etc used as keys. Arrays cannot be modified or have the individual elements worked with - to change the array you would have to re-write it. In my solution (as mentioned) the plan_0, plan_1 etc are placeholders for whatever is generated by childByAutoId. I just didnt feel like typing *-Yj9j99kaj9oir94n9g9* over and over.

Comment: Ahhh! Makes plenty of sense now! I will go ahead and attempt that and get back to check your answer as a solution since I am sure it is. And Lol- isn’t that why we all started developing - to not type or do things over and over again lol. Thanks @Jay

Comment: @CodingwhileLoading Get back to us if you get stuck with the coding. OH - forgot to mention. Please see how I stored the date; *yyyymmdd*. The way you have it stored isn't going to be easy to work with; this format makes it highly searchable, sortable and easily converted to any format with with a DateFormatter in code.

Comment: thanks for the added advice. 1 brief question- for option#2- how would I create an auto ID for all_images and all_plans ? If you see my function above - (uploadPlanitData) - i’m thinking, within that func there would be multiple update child values instead of grouping them together as 1 call like I did?

Comment: @CodingwhileLoading You dont need to. That would be the static parent key name for those nodes, like when users would be in a */users/* node. For example */all_images/-LETR-XJvQsZCOpG-T1N* would refer to the parent node of one post, and then */all_images/-LETR-XKqXf7NY1gh6Jm* would refer to another post. Where you want to use .childByAutoId is the key for each url contained within that references node i.e. */all_plans/-LETR-XJvQsZCOpG-T1N/some_auto_id: urlvalue*

Comment: I updated the answer with a bit more info - hopefully with will get you going the right direction.

Comment: yea i was just kind of scratching my head trying to take all of that in, but the edit helped. ok so i partially i understand that. But how is it possible to achieve that structure when i am using a for loop though? Like how are you able to get all_images & all_plans to have that same key (-LETR-XJvQsZCOpG-T1N) as the planit ? i am currently using this call, im not sure where i would establish that all_images & all_planits share that same key

    _REF_PLANITS.childByAutoId().updateChildValues(["plan" : plan, "date" : withDate, "image": withImage, "title": withTitle, "Uid": uid])

Comment: i hope you understand where my slight confusion lies.

Comment: @CodingwhileLoading Fully understand - it takes a while to wrap your brain around NoSQL databases, asynchronous calls and denormalized data. Check out the updated answer with code.

Comment: That makes so much sense now that you laid it out in code! I understand what is actually happening under the hood. Its mainly based all on the "planKey" that is generated for that Planit child, thats how i can distinguish groups! Thank you. What you coded out makes total sense when i read the data to display on client. But, When i am writing to the DB, i do need to reference that 'key' with "all_images" & "all_plans" nodes - i dont get that part? Like making it so that those nodes are actually stored with a reference to the PlanIt key. i keep gettin an error. Thanks by the way

Comment: @CodingwhileLoading Yes. The plan keys tie everything together so when creating the data, create the main plan node (childByAutoId), and then use that same key to write the child nodes to the images and details node. e.g. let key = refFromChildByAutoId.key

Comment: ok thats what i was looking for. I believe im on the wrong page still, im trying to update the values like this  - But now that you say that, i feel like i should not update them all together, that way i can reference the key on the images, plans and details nodes. _REF_PLANITS.childByAutoId().updateChildValues(["all_plans" : plan, "all_dates" : withDate, "all_images": withImage, "title": withTitle, "Uid": uid])

Comment: @CodingwhileLoading Sounds like you have two things going on. 1) How to structure your data and read it and 2) how to write it in the first place and/or update it once it exists. You will not want to use childByAutoId do perform an update as it creates a new node and updating would be updating an existing node where you already know the (PlanIt) key. This answer addresses how to structure and read it. If you need help figuring out how to write/update it, perhaps another question based on the structure I proposed. Don't forget to accept this answer if it helped.

Comment: thanks for the response. Your solution works for reading, I’ll have to piece together a way to write it. Your insight helped tremendously