# get data select tableview variable swift

Tags: swift, firebase

How can I retrieve the id number of the data that I selected in tableview? I want to draw the id number of the data I selected in the tableview in the application as it appears in the photo. 2> titles> id rankings this way. I want to get the id number when I click on the name. for example, I want to draw the id number of this data when I press bb.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6vSj.png)

Comment: Create a model for id and title and render it in tableview then you can easily get particular data using indexPath.row.

Answer (score 1):

First off, your Firebase structure should probably be simplified and [please don't use arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45785134/create-firebase-database-rule-on-key-name/45804389#45804389). Best practice is to create your keys with .childByAutoId.

```
titles
   child_by_auto_id_0
      title: "bb"
   child_by_auto_id_1
      title: "cc"
```

Then, when you read in your firebase nodes, populate a class, and then store those class objects in a class array

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var myTitleArray: [TitleClass]()

   class TitleClass {
      var id = ""
      var title = ""
   }

   func readFirebaseData() {
       //read firebase, iterate over results and populate array

       let title = TitleClass()
       title.id = snapshot.key //this will be the childByAutoId for each node
       title.title = //get the title from the snapshot
       self.myTitleArray.append(title)

       //when done iterating and populating the array, tableView .reloadData()
    }
```

and in your tableView delegate methods, use the self.myTitleArray as your dataSource

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have an array or something similar to fill the tableview, then you have to implement de delegate func which is in charge to alert when user clicks in a row.
I have took this from another post, but you basically

```
class ViewController : UITableViewController {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedItem = items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as YourObject
        selectedItem.id
    }
}
```